# Bitbake bbappend file percent in filename

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I can't find in the yocto documentation why some bbappend files have a "%" in the filename. An example would the "qtbase_%.bbappend".

Does it mean "apply to all versions of the qtbase bitable recipe"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `%` wildcard is accepted to match any character.  For example

`PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-imx_mx6 = "3.10.17"`

`PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-imx_mx6 = "3.10%"`

> The wildcard is actually allow matching of the name and
>   version up to the point of encountering the %.
>   This approach will
>   allow for matching of the major or major.minor.
>
> Exampes:
>
> `busybox_1.21.1.bb`
>
> `busybox_1.21.%.bbappend will match`
>
> `busybox_1.2%.bbappend will also match`
>
> if we update to busybox_1.3.0.bb the above won't match, but a busybox_1.%.bb
>   will.

http://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/62171/

Comment: Is it possible to specify a wildcard and a specific bbappend in one layer and if so are they prioritized and how?

Comment: Please create a new question.

Comment: Is this explanation correct for the filename too? I have file `systemd_%.bbappend`. Is this mean it can apply for all version of `systemd`?

Comment: % is for file name. And yes, `systemd_%` means all version of systemd